# jQuery delete confirmation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages

In my asp.net application am having a master page and some other pages, in that pages I've add button as well as delete button, for this delete button I've written the delete method in my code behind, its working fine. But before this delete function fires I need to display a delete confirmation box. For this I've written delete confirmation method in the jQuery file named `custom.js` under `Js` folder, and am referring this js file in the master page like

```
<script src="/Js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in this custom.js I've written the delete confirmation method under pageInit of custom.js like

```
function pageInit(){
$(".delete").click(function (event) {
    confirmationBox(event);
    });
}

function confirmationBox(event) {

var r = confirm("You are about to delete some items. Click Ok to continue");
if (r == true) {
    $(document).submit();
}
else {
    event.preventDefault();
}
}
```

and in the scripting am using the class name as delete like

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" class="delete" Text="Delete"/>
```

from the script am calling the js file as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     pageInit();
 });
 </script>
```

but this delete confirmation method is not firing at all, whats wrong with this query, can anyone help me.....

Comment: try using `CssClass` instead of `class`

Comment: @Drew: I tried its not working

Comment: I see, have you also tried using `OnClientClick`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to implement what you are doing is by using the `OnClientClick` event of the ASP.NET Button

```
<asp:Button 
     ID="btnDelete" 
     class="delete" 
     Text="Delete" 
     OnClientClick="return confirmationBox()" />
```

```
function confirmationBox() {
    var r = confirm("You are about to delete some items. Click Ok to continue");
        if (r) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and that should do it :)

[**Update**]
My bad, I forgot to include return on the `OnClientClick` function;
the `return` stops the postback from happening if you choose cancel on the confirmation.

Comment: thanks for ur response, here if I click Ok in the confirmation, the delete method in the codebehind should be fired. how can I call that from jQuery?

Comment: just assign a Click event handler on your button.

Comment: I've a problem here, even If I give cancel in the confirmation window, the delete function in the code behind is firing, how to stop this....

Comment: is there any way to fix this??

Comment: @Shanish I've edited my post, my bad, I forgot to include the `return` on the `OnClientClick` also. I've modified your JS to better make use of this approach.

Answer (score 2):

You should have that delete function inside the $(document).ready():

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
 });
```

Comment: Yep.  The function is firing before the delete class element exists, so nothing happens.

Comment: @Karthick : is it possible to call a cssclass and then the jQuery like <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" CssClass="delete" text="Delete">, y am asking is it was working when I call this Css delete without calling the $(document).ready() in all the pages, but that delete Css is missing now, thats what

Answer (score 1):

your delete button control is present inside the master page. to refer delete button use this syntax input[id$=btn_delete]. bind the button click event in document.ready function. 
following code worked for me.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

<asp:Button ID="btn_delete" runat="server" Text="Delete Confirmation" 
    onclick="btn_delete_Click" />



    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('input[id$=btn_delete]').click(function (event) {
                confirmationBox(event);
            });
        });

    function confirmationBox(event) {

        var r = confirm("You are about to delete some items. Click Ok to continue");
        if (r == true) {
            $(document).submit();
        }
        else {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    </script>
```